How to make the JVM use C2 more than tiered compilation?
Currently focused on using Java 17 in Kubernetes containers.
I've been reading about the Java Hotspot JVM and "tiered compilation" vs "C2".  As far as I can see from the "PrintCompilation" logs, the JIT always uses tiered compilation, it's just that level "4" represents the "C2" level, and 0-3 are simply less than that.
I've been reading about how you might be able to make it more aggressive, by increasing the cpu limit or the memory limit.  I've tried simple experiments of increasing both of those, currently with a cpu limit of 2000m and a memory limit of 3Gi, but the log results look very similar to my "control" build, which has a cpu limit of 750m and a memory limit of 1.5Gi.  The compilation logs show some methods at level 4, and some at the other levels.
Would it require much higher cpu and/or memory limits to make it be more aggressive, or is it not really possible to control this?
